# enable single h:selectbooleancheckbox from many inside rich:datatable in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have a rich:datatable in which I have many columns and one of the columns is h:selectbooleancheckbox. I want the users to select just one of the checkboxes at a time from those many chechboxes in the datatable. If a checkbox is selected once, I have no problem I can submit it to the form. When a second checkbox is selected, for example, the former one should be deselected. How I can do that? Thank you in advance for your help... 
Here is the datatable that I am using:

```
<rich:dataTable id="vehicleTable" var="vhcl" value="#{tripsBacking.vehicleList}"
binding="#{tripsBacking.vehicleTable}" sortMode="single" 
footerClass="dr-table-footer rich-table-footer"
style="width: 500px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<rich:column id="col1" width="10px" headerClass="dr-table-header rich-table-header">
    <f:facet name="header">

    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="#{general.select}" >
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="col2" label="#{general.vehicleName}" headerClass="dr-table-header rich-table-header" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{general.vehicleName}" id="vehicleNameLbl" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{vhcl.vehicle.vehicleName}" id="vehicleNameValue" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column id="col3" label="#{general.vehicleType}" headerClass="dr-table-header rich-table-header" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{general.vehicleType}"
            id="state_capital" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:graphicImage value="#{vhcl.typeImage}" height="40" width="40" align="left"/>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="col4" label="#{general.lastMessageDate}"
    headerClass="dr-table-header rich-table-header" > 
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{general.lastMessageDate}" id="lastMsgDateLabel" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{vhcl.messageDate}" id="lastMsgDate" /> 
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="col5a" label="#{general.address}"
    headerClass="dr-table-header rich-table-header" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{general.address}" id="addressLabel" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{vhcl.address}" id="addr" />
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax submit on every change and have an action listener method that will deselect all previously selected items from the list.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="#{general.select}" >
    <a4j:support event="onclick" listener="#{tripsBacking.selectSingleRow}" reRender="vehicleTable">
       <!-- use property that uniquely identifies a row -->
       <f:attribute name="selectedVehicleName" value="#{general.vehicleName}"/>
    </a4j:support>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

It will be something like the above, where deselectAll is an action listener method in your bean:

```
public void selectSingleRow(ActionEvent event) {
    String vehicleName = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedVehicleName");
    for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
          if (!v.getVehicleName.equals(vehicleName)) {
               v.setSelected(false);     
          }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use primefaces [DataTable - RadioCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)

Comment: f:ajax is not supported in my application. Instead I am using a4j:support. a4j:support has actionListener attribute which I guess can be used in stead of f:ajax listener. How can I deselect all of them in the bean method? can you please give further information? thank you...

Comment: if the problem can be solved in Javascript, how can it be solved? Or how could I solve it with method in the backing bean??? any help would greatly be appreciated...

Comment: I edited my answer to give a clearer example. It will be along those lines. 

You can achieve the same thing with Javascript, but it can be problematic with tables that use pagination.

Comment: Firstly, my table does not use paginatioin. I have a scrollable datatable so I don't use pagination. How can I solve it with Javascript. In my Jsf page, I wrote something like ((<a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{tripsBacking.deselectAll}" reRender="infoForm" />)) code. However, I don't know what to do in the backing bean to deselect all of checkboxes. What should loop through in the bean? I also binded the datatable in the backing bean.

Comment: Take a look at my original answer, I called deselectAll() method selectSingleRow method. It deselects all rows except for one.

Comment: Yes, I checked your answer. It helped me alot. Thank you very very much... I really appreciated that.